# Function to toggle between two values of an enum

Tags: c#, enum

I have this code, but it looks a bit verbose:

```
enum MonitoringMode
{
    Seek,
    Destroy
}
```

```
void ToggleMonitoringMode()
{
    if (_monitoringMode == MonitoringMode.Seek)
        _monitoringMode = MonitoringMode.Destroy;
    else
    if (_monitoringMode == MonitoringMode.Destroy)
        _monitoringMode = MonitoringMode.Seek;
}
```

There are some well known idioms to toggle between two values, like:

> ```
> bitwiseBoolean ^= bitwiseBoolean; // bit toggle
> boolean = !boolean;               // boolean toggle
> oneOrZero = 1 - oneOrZero;        // numeric toggle
> ```

Is there a similar, less verbose way to get the same result? I am not sure using the `int` value of enums would be safe or even "elegant" in C#.

Comment: If your enum only has two values, you don't have an enum, you have a bool.

Comment: @Kevin technicaly speaking it's true but to make the meaning of true/false more verbose I also prefer to use enums in many situations.

Comment: then you are making toggling a lot harder than it has to be.  `bool InDestroyMode =true;`  `InDestroyMode = !InDestroyMode ` is a lot simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: @Kevin pasting my comment on moarboilerplate's answer: I thought about using boolean, but boolean has an "apple vs non-apple" semantics, while I prefer (or actually, the application requires) an "apple vs orange (vs not-yet-considered fruit)" semantics.

Comment: Yes, if you know there are going to be further options later, then boolean is not the way to go

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would there ever be a need to add more values to the `MonitoringMode` enum?

```
enum MonitoringMode
{
    Seek,
    Destroy,
    Something,
    SomethingElse
}
```

In that case, you're not "toggling" - you're *mapping*. And there's a data structure for that:

```
private static readonly IDictionary ModeMap = new Dictionary<MonitoringMode,MonitoringMode>
{
    { MonitoringMode.Seek, MonitoringMode.Destroy },
    { MonitoringMode.Destroy, MonitoringMode.Seek },
    // ...
};
```

Then you could switch from one value to the next simply by using that map:

```
void ToggleMonitoringMode()
{
    _monitoringMode = ModeMap[_monitoringMode];
}
```

---

If there's not going to be a need to ever add more values, then I'd question the use of an `enum` type here, because you're really toggling between `true` and `false` states of some `_isSeeking` Boolean, which you already know how to toggle.

Comment: You're right. I must say I have two modes NOW but they are not intrinsically binary (that is, I can see a lot of future reasons demanding additional modes). I'll wait a little bit before accepting, but this is a very interesting solution indeed! Thanks for now!

Comment: Picking on Mr. Mug a bit here, mapping based on a dictionary turns all of your rules that could be expressed statically in code and unit tested individually into items that are evaluated at runtime, which could be an issue. Especially if diagnosing problems requires peeking into said collection using a debugger

Comment: @moarboilerplate fair point. How about making `ModeMap` public then, and have unit tests that validate the mappings? ...or better - constructor-injected as `IDictionary<MonitoringMode,MonitoringMode> mappingRules`?

Comment: That would work provided the values in your dictionary are all value types or expressions. But it all hinges on the question of why a mapping rule should be stored as a representation of itself and not explicitly coded instructions. If the answer is "developer convenience" that may be problematic.

Comment: Consider AutoMapper--the reason you want to use it is because you can count on it automatically mapping properties with the same name. But if you have custom mapping, you should unit test that. So then you have to introduce the AutoMapper dependency to your unit tests (provided you aren't telling AutoMapper to call methods or objects that are isolated under test)--not unlike the simpler dictionary of maps. Is it worth making all of your unit tests have a prerequisite?

Comment: @moarboilerplate aren't you *just a little bit* over-complicating this? ;-)

Comment: You'd think so, but the things I've seen, man.

Comment: I can't help saying that now the `ModeMap` property looks a lot like the original `ToggleMonitoringMode` method... (only of course now the implementation details are nicely encapsulated away from the method code, which might or might not be considered an advantage). Not that I find this better or worse.

Comment: Quite frankly, I would rather have a couple of `if-else`s in my code, than dictionary maps. With maps you can't group conditions like `if (mode==Mode1 || mode==Mode2) {...} else {...}`. Also any extra dependency to "toggling" logic such as `if (mode==Mode1 && Enabled) {...}` will double the size of the dictionary. Not to mention that debugging those maps is an annoyance.

Comment: In Java there's a way to lookup an enum value by index, such as `MonitoringMode.values()[index]`, is this not possible in C#?

Answer (score 2):

If you are into bit-twiddling, you can have your cake and eat it too with the `[Flags]` attribute. However, I would only use this when you want to represent combinations of more than one value, you want to execute conditionals based on these values, and/or your zeroth value has significant meaning (but I'd still use a bool for simplicity over a 2-item enum).

Comment: That's a good option (the Flags attribute). I thought about using boolean, but boolean has a "apple vs non-apple" semantics, while I prefer (or actually, the application deserves) an "apple vs orange" semantics.

Comment: I would really only use the flags if your values are additive qualities. So apple would not be `Apple`, it would be `GrowsOnTree | IsRed` (terrible example, I've never thought so hard about how to classify an apple). Maybe what you're really after is the concept of a [discriminated union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx)?